# "There is no ‘my’ neighbor who/whom I don't like" - Can I use a possessive pronoun after "there is no"?

Tags: word-choice, relative-pronouns, who-whom

I wanted to know if I can use possessive pronoun  after "There is no".

Example:"

> There is no **my** neighbor **who/whom** I don't like.

I also wanted to know which word I should use - "who" or "whom"?

Comment: No, but it seems to me that you can say "There is no neighbour **of mine** whom I don't like".

Answer (score 1):

We cannot usually put a possessive between another determiner and a noun. We can use *determiner + noun + of + possessive* instead.

> My work is no business of yours.
>   There is no neighbour of mine whom I don't like.

We use whom, because it functions as an object in the clause .